# Gembox Document prevent pagebreak in table?

Tags: c#, page-break, gembox-document

Is it possible in [Gembox.Document](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview) to insert a table to a document and prevent it from being split by a page break but instead move it to the next page if it does not fit on the previous page? 
I have looked through the samples and the documentation but not found anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `KeepLinesTogether` and `KeepWithNext` properties to `true` for paragraphs that are located in that table. For example, try the following:

```
Table table = ...

foreach (ParagraphFormat paragraphFormat in table
    .GetChildElements(true, ElementType.Paragraph)
    .Cast<Paragraph>()
    .Select(p => p.ParagraphFormat))
{
    paragraphFormat.KeepLinesTogether = true;
    paragraphFormat.KeepWithNext = true;
}
```

**EDIT**
The above will work for most cases, however, the problem can occur when the `Table` element has empty `TableCell` elements, that do not have any `Paragraph` elements.

For this, we need to add an empty `Paragraph` element to those `TableCell` elements so that we can set the desired formatting (source: [Keep tables on same page](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/word-table-formatting/1204#prevent-table-breaks)):

```
// Get all Paragraph formats in a Table element.
IEnumerable<ParagraphFormat> formats = table
    .GetChildElements(true, ElementType.TableCell)
    .Cast<TableCell>()
    .SelectMany(cell =>
    {
        if (cell.Blocks.Count == 0)
            cell.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(cell.Document));
        return cell.GetChildElements(true, ElementType.Paragraph);
    })
    .Cast<Paragraph>()
    .Select(p => p.ParagraphFormat);
 
// Set KeepLinesTogether and KeepWithNext properties.
foreach (ParagraphFormat format in formats)
{
    format.KeepLinesTogether = true;
    format.KeepWithNext = true;
}
```